Fix $0<r<1$. If $r<|z|<\frac{1}{r}$, prove $r<\frac{1}{2}|z+\frac{1}{z}|<\frac{1}{r}$.
Fix $0<r<1$. If $r<|z|<\frac{1}{r}$, prove that $r<\frac{1}{2}|z+\frac{1}{z}|<\frac{1}{r}$.
I can prove the right-side inequality, $\frac{1}{2}|z+\frac{1}{z}|<\frac{1}{r}$ as follows:
Since $r<|z|<\frac{1}{r}$, we know that $r<\frac{1}{|z|}<\frac{1}{r}$. Then by the triangle inequality,
$\frac{1}{2}|z+\frac{1}{z}|\le \frac{1}{2}|z|+\frac{1}{2}|\frac{1}{z}| <\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{r}$. Thus $\frac{1}{2}|z+\frac{1}{z}|<\frac{1}{r}$.
But I cannot prove the left-side inequality, i.e. $r<\frac{1}{2}|z+\frac{1}{z}|$. Any suggestions?

Note that $z$ is a complex number and $r$ is a real number.

Is there any further assumptions on $z$? If $z=i$ and $r=1/2$ then $z+1/z=0$, and the inequality you want is incorrect.

You are right. I guess I should rephrase the question to prove or disprove $r<\frac{1}{2}|z+\frac{1}{z}|<\frac{1}{r}$.

Good counterexample!

For  $z=i$ we have $z^{-1}=-i.$ Hence ${1\over 2}(z+z^{-1})=0.$ Thus the lower inequality fails.
You cannot save the lower inequality, unless you assume $z$ is real, or equivalently the arguments od $z$ and $z^{-1}$ are equal.
The transformation $w={1\over 2}(z+z^{-1})$ is called the Zhukovsky function. It maps $r^{-1}< |z|<r$ onto the interior of the ellipse with half axes ${1\over 2}(r^{-1}+r)$ and ${1\over 2}(r^{-1}-r).$

Thanks for the answer. So if $z$ is real or the arguments of $z$ and $z^{-1}$ are equal, i.e. $|z|=|z^{-1}|$, then how to solve the lower inequality?

@John If $z$ is real then $z,1/z$ has the same sign, and so we reduce to prove that $|z|+1/|z|>2r$, which is clearly true since $r<|z|<1/r$.
